# Create a Python or R script that can download Bhav.zip file from the NSE website

Tags: python, r

I need to automatically download bhav.zip files from the National Stock Exchange (NSE) website (Link given below) for a given date range (lets say May 1 to May 5, 2017) but I am unable to do so.
https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm

Comment: You need selenium webdriver to do this

Comment: Please show us what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

The URL to download the zip file for a particular date looks like it follows a pattern,

For example:
for downloading the data on 5th May 2017:
The link looks like,
`https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2017/MAY/cm05MAY2017bhav.csv.zip`

That is, the URL follows a pattern like,
`https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/{year}/{month in captial letters}/cm{date}{month in captial letters}{year}bhav.csv.zip`

you could simply write a for loop to iterate through the dates and save them individually!

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. One question though, how did you get the exact URL to download the bhavcopy. For example if I try to now download from the BSE website how do I get it?

Comment: Simple, I visited the link that you gave,and tried to download the data for a particular date,and while downloading I saw the URL is not dynamically generated but a static one. So I tried changing the date in the URL and it worked!

Comment: Thanks a lot... I used the following python code to download the data. However it always shows the given error:

Comment: just to mention, month name should always three characters. ie; JANUARY should be shortened to JAN and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Package `nser` helps you to download and read bhavcopy from NSE.

```
library(nser)
# Download todays bhavcopy
bhavtoday()
# Download historical bhavcopy
bhav("12082021")
```

To download bhavcopy zipfile by RSelenium use `bhavs`

Package
https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/nser/index.html